# При попытке вызова box.cfg {} в tarantool процесс просто завершается

Tags: tarantool

Я учусь работать с субд tarantool и пытаюсь вызвать box.cfg{}, но в ответ tarantool просто выводит следующую ошибку и завершает процесс.

```
tarantool> box.cfg{}
2021-02-23 21:24:41.355 [52053] main/103/interactive C> Tarantool 2.6.2-0-g34d504d7d
2021-02-23 21:24:41.355 [52053] main/103/interactive C> log level 5
2021-02-23 21:24:41.355 [52053] main/103/interactive I> mapping 268435456 bytes for memtx tuple arena...
2021-02-23 21:24:41.355 [52053] main/103/interactive I> Actual slab_alloc_factor calculated on the basis of desired slab_alloc_factor = 1.044274
2021-02-23 21:24:41.356 [52053] main/103/interactive I> mapping 134217728 bytes for vinyl tuple arena...
2021-02-23 21:24:41.358 [52053] main/103/interactive box.cc:2984 E> ER_ALREADY_RUNNING: Failed to lock WAL directory . and hot_standby mode is off
2021-02-23 21:24:41.358 [52053] main/103/interactive F> can't initialize storage: Failed to lock WAL directory . and hot_standby mode is off
```

Comment: Попробуй запустить с параметром: box.cfg{listen = 3301}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, tarantool запущен в другой консоли на том же порте (по умолчанию 3301), или в доке (тоже занимает порт 3301)

Вот что я сделал чтобы решить эту проблему у себя

```bsh
# install netstat
sudo apt-get net-tools
# check what takes port :3301
sudo netstat -pna | grep 3301
#kill *process_number* that takes port :3301
kill -TERM *process_number*
```